# How to use Node.js to run .exec() as a specific user?

Tags: node.js, impersonation

I'm building a custom VSTS release task. I'm using Node and typescript. I need to execute the task as a specific user (impersonate), because the build-agent doesn't have the required permissions to execute the task.

As I see it I have two choices:

1. Execute the entire task as a specific user.
2. Since I'm using the [toolrunner](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/node/docs/vsts-task-lib.md) I could execute only the toolrunner with my specific credentials.

Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation for [the task schema](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/master/tasks.schema.json) or the [task-lib](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/node/README.md) on this. My code currently looks something like this (simplified):

```
let tRunner:trm.ToolRunner = tl.tool(toolPath);
tRunner.arg(["--someArgument", someArgument])
await tRunner.exec();
```

I need the `rTunner.exec()` to run as another user than the build agent. I can pass the credentials to the task.

In PowerShell I would have done something like this:

```
$pswd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username, $pswd)

$ScriptBlock = { 
    param($args) 
    -- Execute here...
}

Invoke-Command -Credential $cred  $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $args
```

What's the equalent way in Node?

Comment: Your choice 1 is not able to achieve for now. There is not such build-in solution. For choice 2, the issue is not related to VSTS task, more related to Node.js side, how to use  Node.js to run .exec() as a specific user? So suggest you remove TFS/VSTS related tag.

Comment: @Chamberlain - I noticed that you removed the vsts-tag. I'm not sure if I agree since the question mainly focuses on how it's possible to accomplish this in TFS. Node just happens to be the platform of choice.